# PostgreSQL - how to define a user-defined function with dynamic parameters?

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions

As i know, when you create a user-defined function in postgresql, you must specify the parameters numbers and types.  Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_add(xx INTEGER, yy INTEGER) 
 RETURNS INTEGER AS 
 $$
   BEGIN
     RETURN xx + yy;
   END;
 $$ 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select my_add(12, 34);
output: 46
```

Now i want to create a function which can receive dynamic parameters and works like this:

```
select my_add(1, 2);
output: 3

select my_add(1, 2, 3);
output: 6

select my_add(10, 4, 5, 1);
output: 20
```

Is there some ways to define dynamic parameters when you define your function ? How can i do that? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for [variadic parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS), e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mleast(VARIADIC arr numeric[]) RETURNS numeric AS $$
    SELECT min($1[i]) FROM generate_subscripts($1, 1) g(i);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: @hyman - `CREATE FUNCTION my_concat(VARIADIC arr text[]) RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT array_to_string(arr, '');
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;` Then call: `select my_concat('hello', 'world', '.');`

Comment: Thanks very much! your code is worked to handle numeric operations. but if i want to define a function like 'concat', what should i do? like this: `select my_concat('hello', 'world', '.'); output: helloworld.`

Comment: @Oto Shavadze Do you know how it works on GreenPlum? I have tried some ways but failed.   `CREATE FUNCTION my_concat(VARIADIC arr text[]) RETURNS text AS $$ SELECT array_to_string(arr, ''); $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "text" at character 40
LINE 1: CREATE FUNCTION my_concat(VARIADIC arr text[]) RETURNS text ...`  Thanks!

Comment: @hyman: If I paste your function into Postgres 9.5.5 it works as expected.